# order of execution in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI with tkinter, I want that the splash screen should render first and then the rest of the widgets. But that is not happening, they both are rendering simultaneously.

```py
m = tkinter.Tk()
width = m.winfo_screenwidth()
height = m.winfo_screenheight()
m.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
m.title("Aircrack-ng")
Splash_screen.splash_screen(m, width, height, 100)
network_label = tkinter.Label(m, text="Do u have the network adapter connected??")
btn_yes = tkinter.Button(m, text="Yes", width=15, command=check_aircrack)
btn_no = tkinter.Button(m, text="No", width=15, command=m.destroy)
network_label.pack()
btn_yes.pack()
btn_no.pack()
Menubar.window(m)
m.mainloop()
```

The one above is the main window.

The one below is the splash screen:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font


def splash_screen(window, width, height, font_size):
    def destroy():
        splash_screen_label.destroy()

    fontStyle = font.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=font_size)
    splash_screen_label = Label(window, text="The Aircrack-ng Suite", font=fontStyle)
    x_pos = width / 2
    y_pos = height / 2
    splash_screen_label.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos, anchor=CENTER)
    # splash_screen_label.pack()
    window.after(3000, destroy)
```

I am new to programming, please help.

Comment: it first reaches the mainloop and then executes everything in the order You packed them but it just happens pretty quickly, adding sleep in between won't help but YOu could try using `.after()`

Comment: Add `window.wait_window(splash_screen_label)` at the end of `splash_screen()` function.

Comment: K will try the methods u both gave , thnx :)